# Generating Javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

An assignment I'm working on asks for :

*Reasonable inline code documentation, providing Javadoc generated documentation, with method descriptions, parameter  and return value descriptions.*

Isn't that just /**? Or would it the eclipse generated version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are just asking for the code to be properly commented, in a way such that they can later extract the documentation via the `javadoc` tool. You should follow all the [Javadoc best practices](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html), and of course if you want extra credit, run the documentation phase of your build to actually generate the docs. I'm sure they will love that.

Answer (score 0):

"Javadoc generated documentation" would be the HTML documentation generated from the `/**` comments in the code. I don't know whether eclipse has a function for that, but it is generally done with the [`javadoc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) command line tool that comes with the JDK.